# Scroll down a table with fixed header in robot framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I need to scroll down, but the problem is the scrolling is not applied in whole page its only a table body.

i tried **Set_focus_on_element** and **move_over** to the table and then tried scrolling but it didnt work.

to scroll till the element is located i used

```
Execute Javascript   window.document.evaluate("${xpath}", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView(true)
```

This seems to work fine on other places but to scroll only Table body, first i need to set focus there, but no luck so far

Comment: Really!!! no answers.. :('

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with Java and javascript everything is working fine. Hope for you it would also work.

First get the webelement:

WebElement we = driver.findelement(By.xpath("your xpath")) // make sure it should present on DOM, if it not them need to move scroll down or scroll up then again try to find the webElement.

if you get the webelement then use below code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", we);
```

For scroll down:

```
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight || document.documentElement.scrollHeight)", "");
```

For scroll Up:

```
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-document.body.scrollHeight || -document.documentElement.scrollHeight)", "");
```

Height can be adjusted according to your need like:

```
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,(-document.body.scrollHeight)/4 || -(document.documentElement.scrollHeight)/4)", "");
```

Comment: I guess you are scrolling on whole page. I need to scroll only on a scroll-able table till the element in the table is found and table is in the actual website

Comment: I mentioned all the options. First option you can use to scroll to your table.

Answer (score -1):

swipe left move to right in the table view
code
sleep  1
Swipe  x    y(constant)  x    y(constant)

example
sleep  1
Swipe  .8    564     .3   564

make sure you will gives y coordinate where the table view is present.
so that you can easily scroll in